# Force TinyMCE editor's "Toolbar Toggle" to be automatically chosen & expanded

Tags: editor

A common problem we have with new Wordpress installations and particularly new users, is that their "Toolbar Toggle" button is not selected by default, and therefore the second line of the editor icons don't show.

Is there a way to force this option to always be selected?

[image: Toolbar Toggle icon]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add below function in your activated theme's functions.php file.

```
function changeMceDefaults($in) {

    // customize the buttons
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons1'] = 'bold,italic,underline,bullist,numlist,hr,blockquote,link,unlink,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,outdent,indent';         
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons2'] = 'formatselect,pastetext,pasteword,charmap,undo,redo';

    // Keep the "kitchen sink" open
    $in[ 'wordpress_adv_hidden' ] = FALSE;
    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'changeMceDefaults' );
```

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for something exactly like this.  Works great.

Comment: @Buckers , Great enjoy.!

Comment: If you want to use it with `wp_editor` use it like this: `wp_editor($value, $id, ['tinymce'] => ['wordpress_adv_hidden' => false])`